# Designing a power supply circuit for a DC motor speed control circuit

Tags: transformer, dc-motor, 555, proteus

I am designing a a power supply circuit for a DC motor speed control circuit.

I am using Proteus to simulate it but it is not working.

I am using a step down transformer to take 230V to 16V then regulating it to 12V. The 12V is supposed to be connected to the Vcc of the 555 timer and the motor but it is either the motor doesn't run or it is very slow. When I use the 12V DC generator, the motor is very fast.

[image]

I changed it to this but it is still not working:

[image]

Comment: OK. So you mean a real world circuit made of that schematic does not work, or it does not work in the simulator? What motor it is, how much current or power it needs to operate? Also your transistor Q1 may be damaged already. Or the LED D8. Or the regulator.

Comment: 1.)Get a meter. 2) Start measuring voltages. 3) Report back

Comment: @Justme I mean that it doesn't work in the simulator. I haven't made the real-world version yet. It is a 12V DC motor. I don't know how much current or power it needs. It is a motor from the Proteus library. What do you suggest I do?

Comment: @Davide Andrea, Which voltages am I measuring? The voltage at the output of the regulator without the diode is 12V and with the diode is approximately 2.2V

Comment: You should debug the circuit in Proteus then. Measure voltages, currents, and waveforms.

Comment: "Which voltages am I measuring". Every single node. Mark the voltage on the schematic diagram and post it.

Comment: @Tolu - Hi, Now that you have received answers to the question about the circuit in your original question, it is too late to change the question to a different circuit, as it makes the previous answers invalid. Therefore I have reversed (rolled-back) your last edit. || If you have questions about a new circuit then please ask a new question, include a link back to this one for context, explain what you changed & especially *why* you changed it in that way. Now you said you're getting a simulation error message, please include that in the new question. Also explain your own analysis so far. TY

Comment: @SamGibson - Okay. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Q1 should have a resistor in series with its base. If you have connected it up as shown it may be blown as a result of shoving too much current into its base.

Put a resistor in series with the LED.

Greatly increase the size of C4 (say to 10,000 uF to start with). If you are drawing a large current for the motor there may be a very large ripple voltage going into the regulator which may be forcing the voltage down on the regulator's output.

Comment: Okay. What value of resistor should I use?

Comment: @Tolu The resistor value depends on how much current the motor draws. You could do a little experiment in the simulator - connect the motor up to a stand-alone +12 V supply with an ammeter in series to determine the motor's required current. Then you can decide if a BD139 has a high enough hFE bearing in mind the output current limitations of the 555 and considering how much the 555's output will be pulled down under load. Then you can then get an idea of the required base resitor value.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one problem (another answer already mentioned a different one): You have connected an LED D8 directly across the output of the 12 V regulator, with no current-limiting resistor. In real life, that would damage the LED. In Proteus, I guess it will limit that voltage to approximately Vf of that LED.

Remove that LED (or add around a 2k series resistor, to get around 5mA current, depending on the LED colour) and re-test.

Also, as mentioned, you can improve your question by measuring voltages at relevant points on your schematic and adding that detail into the question.